# Nginx: some rewrite rules are working and some aren't

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I've got one nginx conf file with 2060 rewrite rules for a pretty large website.

The weird thing is: only about half of the rewrite rules are actually redirecting. The other half just takes you to the php application that shows a 404 because the page doesn't exist.

These 2 rules are actually returning a 301 code and are correctly redirecting the visitor:

```
rewrite ^/rechtsgebied/consumentenrecht/columns/169/boek-over-loverboy-verzonnen_-consument-kan-geld-terugeisen.htm/?$ https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/consumentenrecht/columns/boek-over-loverboy-verzonnen-consument-kan-geld-terugeisen/ permanent;
```

301, after redirect: https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/consumentenrecht/columns/169/boek-over-loverboy-verzonnen_-consument-kan-geld-terugeisen.htm

```
rewrite ^/rechtsgebied/bouwen%2C_wonen_%26_huren/huren-van-woonruimte/tipsentrucs/?$ https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/bouwen-wonen-huren/huren-van-woonruimte/tips-and-tricks/ permanent;
```

301, after redirect: https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/bouwen%2C_wonen_%26_huren/huren-van-woonruimte/tipsentrucs

But these two rules aren't doing anything. These URL's aren't being redirected and return a 404:

```
rewrite ^/rechtsgebied/consumentenrecht/kopen-aan-de-deur/artikelen/980/wat-zijn-mijn-rechten-als-consument-bij-koop-aan-huis-%28colportage%29_-.htm/?$ https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/consumentenrecht/kopen-aan-de-deur/artikelen/wat-zijn-mijn-rechten-als-consument-bij-koop-aan-huis-colportage/ permanent;
```

404, no redirect: https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/consumentenrecht/kopen-aan-de-deur/artikelen/980/wat-zijn-mijn-rechten-als-consument-bij-koop-aan-huis-%28colportage%29_-.htm

```
rewrite ^/rechtsgebied/bouwen%2C_wonen_%26_huren/zelf-een-huis-laten-bouwen/artikelen/406/de-aannemingsovereenkomst-in-het-kort.htm/?$ https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/bouwen-wonen-huren/zelf-een-huis-laten-bouwen/artikelen/de-aannemingsovereenkomst-in-het-kort/ permanent;
```

404, no redirect https://www.example.com/rechtsgebied/bouwen%2C_wonen_%26_huren/zelf-een-huis-laten-bouwen/artikelen/406/de-aannemingsovereenkomst-in-het-kort.htm

**EDIT:** I found out that, as soon as I remove the %-signs from the rewrite rule the rule works. (But for the wrong URL obviously.)

**SOLVED:** I ran search-replace queries to replace all bits with `%` (for example `%2C` and `%26`) with `(.*)`. Then I made sure there is never `(.*)(.*)`. And now I`m testing every redirect with a bulk redirect checker ([example](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/redirect-checker/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** I ran search-replace queries to replace all bits with `%` (for example `%2C` and `%26`) with `(.*)`. Then I made sure there is never `(.*)(.*)`. And now I`m testing every redirect with a bulk redirect checker ([example](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/redirect-checker/)).